# Temporarily swap image in button's background after click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, background

I have prepared a two graphics for background of my button. I have one put in "android:background" in xml file and I have no idea how to make to change this image for another image for a while after click.

I tried to do this using OnHoverListener and OnClickListener but it doesn't work

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.img_hovered));
Button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img));
        }
    });
```

Comment: your question isnt clear, you want to make it as clickable button, or you want to change the background after click?

Comment: What I mean is that when you click this button his background would be swapped for a moment (0,5 sec) to another image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make it clickable button, then make a selector xml in drawable folder and copy below code.

lets take its name as app_click.xml

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourimage_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourimage_unpressed"/>
 </selector>
```

then use this selector for your button `Selector`.

like this

```
<Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/app_click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

See if the following does what you are looking for. The code assumes that `R.drawable.img` is the original background. When `Button` is clicked, the background changes to `R.drawable.img_hovered` for 0.5 seconds. Then it reverts back to `R.drawable.img`:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                              R.drawable.img_hovered));

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img));

                // Button Click Code Here
            }

        }, 500L);    // 0.5 Seconds

    }

});
```